# React Native How can I change the App Icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I am coding my first React Native app with Expo and I have it, now I want to change de App icon but I do not know how to do it, I already saw a lot of posts and watch videos but in all of them, people have two folders called Android and iOS in which they can change the icons for each resolution but I do not have it and I can not find them. Here is an image of project.

[image]

Do anyone knows where are the folders or how can I change the App icon?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the icon in the window tab if you were to open it in web?if so one way is to go into the /assets folder and replace the favicon.png with your icon file. remember to rename it as <favicon.png> too.

Comment: Hi, I mean the icon app in mobile for both Android and iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the Icon Images:
192x192 pixels (for Android)
1024x1024 pixels (for iOS)

After that in your **app.json** file, change the path of the icon under the "expo" section

```js
"expo": {
  "icon": "./path/to/your/icon.png",
  // other configuration options
}
```

After that run your expo app using "expo start" command.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your comment. How can I have two icons (192x192 and 1024x1024) with the same name?

Comment: I do not know. How can I have two icons (192x192 and 1024x1024) with the same name?